# Translate powershell query to vb.net query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, powershell

What is the vb.net equivalent for these four lines in powershell. It's related to my other question regarding generating a dropdownlist on a webpage. From a powershell perspective I know this query generates a list. Thanks.

```
$dom = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest]::GetCurrentForest()
$domnames = $dom.Domains
$fqdns = $domnames | Select -exp Name
$fqdns = $fqdns
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked to populate dropdownbox1 in the default.aspx page

```
   Public Function EnumerateDomains() As ArrayList
    Dim alDomains As New ArrayList()
    Dim currentForrest As Forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest()
    Dim myDomains As DomainCollection = currentForrest.Domains
    For Each objDomain As Domain In myDomains
        alDomains.Add(objDomain.Name)
    Next
    Return alDomains
   End Function

   Public Function EnumerateDomains() As ArrayList
    Dim alDomains As New ArrayList()
    Dim currentForrest As Forest = Forest.GetCurrentForest()
    Dim myDomains As DomainCollection = currentForrest.Domains
    For Each objDomain As Domain In myDomains
        alDomains.Add(objDomain.Name)
    Next
    Return alDomains
   End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Below example is in `C#`. Hopefully, you can easily get it converted in `VB.NET`.

Add a reference of `System.DirectoryServices` assembly and then use below code sample

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Forest fc = Forest.GetCurrentForest();
            DomainCollection dc = fc.Domains;
            foreach (var item in dc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in single line using LINQ:

```
Dim fqdns As String() = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetCurrentForest().Domains.[Select](Function(x) x.Name).ToArray()
```

This assigns a value to an array of string named `fqdns`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can make your code work:

```
 Dim Domains As DomainCollection = Forest.GetCurrentForest.Domains

            For Each obj In Domains
                 ComboBox1.Items.Add(obj.Name)
            Next obj
```